# Is there a way to get power consumption in ARM CPUs?

Tags: arm, cpu, energy

Intel CPUs from SandyBridge and newer have MSRs that allow to get an accurate energy consumption (Measured in micro joules). These are visible to the kernel (RAPL - Running average power limit).  Is there an equivalent option for ARM CPUs?

Comment: you are talking about intel chips vs foundry independent IP.  Two completely different things.  Need to ask about a specific chip.  Intels are a bit of a power hog so power measurements make sense.  Wonder if you really need that for arm based chips.

Comment: granted the processor is only part of the power consumption of the system. are you only interested in the main chip or the system?

Comment: Yes. I am interested in the effect of workloads specifically on the CPU. Intel RAPL gives a very accurate read even on low power chips. Are there _any_ ARM based chips that implement something similar?

Comment: You need to go and read the documentation on these chips to find out.